# i am trying to run this GreetingClient program but its giving me error

Tags: java, cmd

its giving me error like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0 
at GreetingClient.main(GreetingClient.java:8)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class GreetingClient{
public static void main(String [] args)
 {
 String serverName = args[0];
  int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  try
  {
  System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
     Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
     System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
     OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream out =new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
     out.writeUTF("Hello from "+ client.getLocalSocketAddress());
     InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
     System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
     client.close();
  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You have to check args.length first.

Comment: @Dmytro its probably 0 and wont help solving the problem.

Comment: Add default values for this case or ensure you run the app with proper arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to start the programm with agruments.

```
java GreetingClient myServer 1337
```

[Here is an official tutorial for that topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

While compiling, you will be writing, java GreetingClient servername . therefore make the following modifications to your code, 
    String serverName = args[2];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[3])